# Script to recreate Outlook 2010 mail profile

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2010

I need to recreate a load of users' mail profiles in Outlook 2010. (It's a long story!)

To try and reduce "user error" I want to script this, so that it removes the user's mail profile, and recreates a replacement.

Is this possible? I've seen the Customer Maintenance Wizard for Outlook 2003, but can't find an equivalent for 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook 2010 will use auto configuration if you're able to set up the appropriate DNS records.  This doesn't completely automate the process, but it will reduce the process to maybe 2-3 steps and eliminate 90% of the configuration work they have to do.  All they (in theory) would need to know is their Name, email address, and password.

Comment: Cool - this could work. Found the following to assist me in removing the existing profile: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlook/thread/33c5149d-7c69-4901-aa85-c9147bbeeccd/ - once removed I guess it should autocreate again

Comment: This would only work if it were Exchange 2007/2010, which it is not.

Comment: @Cheekaleak You are correct, I thought this worked with Exchange 2003 as well, but I guess not. =(

Comment: Actually this worked with Exch 2003. Was getting error 0x80070057, but applying a hotfix (kb2281463) sorted this, and autoconfigure worked

Comment: Awesome!  That's good to know.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assumming a single machine here with an Outlook client that does not involve Exchange.

When I upgraded my home machine from XP / Office 2003 --> Win 7 / Office 2010, I unfortunately noticed that many of the outlook settings and configurations were not contained in the PST file.  I extracted this information from the user registry used in XP and imported them into the Win 7 registry.  My settings basically came back.

My specific concern centered because I use my outlook client to access many different mailboxes on different machines.  But this did the trick and I did not have to go through the effort of manually adding (much less remembering what I had done before).

In your case, find the specific area in the users' registry, save it, do the update.

BTW, I recently upgraded inplace from 2003 ---> 2010 at work and all my settings survived and were properly converted.

Answer (score 0):

I have this script as a favorite, so people can do this themselves whenever they run into an issue with their outlook profile.

- It verifies if the user wants to run the script.
- Closes Outlook.
- Clears configured profiles in the user's registry.
- Creates new profile (*you can edit the new profile name with %username% if you'd like.)
- Opens Outlook with new profile for the user.

**Script:**

```
'
' Use this script when user's emails get stuck in Outbox
' l0c0b0x/jb put this one together 9/13/2012
' Change log
' 1.0 initial release
' 1.1 Added registry string to specify a default profile on the account
' -----------------------------------------------------------

' Ask user if they wish to continue with re-creation of their ouotlook profile
intAnswer = _
    Msgbox("This script will remove and recreate your outlook profile on this computer.  Would you like to continue?", _
        vbYesNo, "Reset Outlook Profile")

If intAnswer = vbYes Then

Else
    WScript.Quit
End If

' Close all instances of Outlook
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set objWmg = GetObject("winmgmts:") 
strWndprs = "select * from Win32_Process where name='outlook.exe'" 
Set objQResult = objWmg.Execquery(strWndprs) 
For Each objProcess In objQResult
    intReturn = objProcess.Terminate(1) 
Next

' Remove registry keys for Outlook Profile
On Error Resume Next
const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles"
DeleteSubkeys HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath

Sub DeleteSubkeys(reghive, KeyPath) 
    Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
    objReg.EnumKey reghive, KeyPath, arrrSubkeys 

    If IsArray(arrrSubkeys) Then 
        For Each strrSubkey In arrrSubkeys 
            DeleteSubkeys reghive, KeyPath & "\" & strrSubkey 
        Next 
    End If 

    objReg.DeleteKey reghive, KeyPath 

End Sub
' Add registry key for new profile
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\newprofile"
oReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath

' Add registry string to specify default profile
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles"
strValueName = "DefaultProfile"
strValue = "newprofile"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue

' Launch Outlook
objShell.Run "outlook.exe"
```