# How can I recreate the default mail profile for an exchange outlook account without removing the old one?

Tags: exchange, outlook-2010

My company's policy is to keep the old email profile while setting a new one to open by default. I have found a vbs script that will recreate the profile no problem but it also removes all existing ones. I've tried reading through the script but I don't know the vbs language at all. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to review your existing script and make a modification to create a new profile without removing the old one. Once you create the new profile, you just need to set it as the default afterward

Here are some links hopefully that will help you
[NameSpace.Logon Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861594.aspx)
[Which registry keys determine the Outlook Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502664/which-registry-keys-determine-the-outlook-profile)

Additionally, here is another one that might help
[Script to recreate Outlook 2010 mail profile](https://serverfault.com/questions/319213/script-to-recreate-outlook-2010-mail-profile) 
You might want to consider testing the void out of "objReg.DeleteKey reghive, KeyPath" portion to see if that can achieve creating new profile without deleting the old one

Edit on replying the comment from Feb3:
I don' think there is an easy way to answer this. It probably require some extra work to create a list of users should use default profile, versus a list of users that should prompt because their work requires accessing multiple profiles.

There is a registry key to enable or disable the prompt for the default profile. It can be implemented via GPO. You can find more on [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/f55b730d-9efb-47c4-b74a-7d7910d6d84a/mail-default-profile?forum=onlineservicesexchange). You can also modifying HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsytem\Profiles\Default Profile to set the default for those users too

Comment: Ok so commenting out that line worked like a charm however we deal with some users that have two or more mail boxes and others that only have one. Those users are sorted into separate groups. So is there a way to run it that it reads the user's groups for a specific string and choose whether or not to set a default profile with no prompt?